# Probability and gcd

Tags: probability, number-theory

Is there any short heuristic explanation or proof of why
$$
\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}
$$
where $a,b$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You are going to have to define your probability better, for example $a$ and $b$ independently uniformly selected from $1,2,3,\ldots,n$, and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$

Comment: The handwaving calculation will be that you cannot have both divisible by any prime, so something like $\prod\limits_{p\text{ prime}} \left(1-\frac1{p^2}\right)$ which is indeed $\frac6{\pi^2}$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hueristic behind Euler products used in asymptotics is to treat prime-power factors of integers as *independent random variables*, which means for any "event" which can be broken up into a logical conjunction of "independent" prime-specific events we can calculate the probability as a product of probabilities. For instance, "squarefree" is equivalent to "(not divisible by $2^2$) and (not divisible by $3^3$) and (not divisible by $5^2$) and (not divisible by $7^2$) and ..." The "probability" of not being divisible by a prime $p^2$ is the complement of the "probability" it *is* divisible, i.e. $1-1/p^2$. Therefore the "probability" a number is squarefree is $\prod(1-1/p^2)=1/\zeta(2)$.

For two numbers not sharing a factor, this is equivalent to "(not both divisible by $2$) and (not both divisible by $3$) and (not both divisible by $5$) and (not both divisible by $7$) and ..." which has the same result.